# Pandas how to get row number from datetime index and back again?

Tags: pandas, date, datetime

I have great difficulties. I have read a csv files, and set the index on "Timestamp" column like this

```
# df = pd.read_csv (csv_file, quotechar = "'", decimal = ".", delimiter=";", parse_dates = True, index_col="Timestamp")


# df

                      XYZ  PRICE  position  nrLots posText  
Timestamp                                                    
2014-10-14 10:00:29   30    140      -1.0    -1.0     buy   
2014-10-14 10:00:30   21     90      -1.0    -5.0     buy   
2014-10-14 10:00:31    3    110       1.0     2.0    sell   
2014-10-14 10:00:32   31    120       1.0     1.0    sell   
2014-10-14 10:00:33    4     70      -1.0    -5.0     buy
```

So if I want to get the price of 2nd row, I want to do like this:

```
df.loc [2,"PRICE"]
```

But that does not work. If I want to use df.loc[] operator, I need to insert a Timestamp, like this:

```
df.loc["2014-10-14 10:00:31", "PRICE"]
```

If I want to use row numbers, I need to do like this instead:

```
df["PRICE"].iloc[2]
```

which sucks. The syntax is ugly. However, it works. I can get the value, and I can set the value - which is what I want.

If I want to find the Timestamp from a row, I can do like this:

```
df.index[row]
```

Question) Is there a more elegant syntax to get and set the value, when you always work with a row number? I always iterate over the row numbers, never iterate over Timestamps. I never use the Timestamp to access values, I always use row numbers.

Bonusquestion) If I have a Timestamp, how can I find the corresponding row number?

Comment: If you don't use Timestamp to index, you could reset index to have it as a column, and a numerical index. Or you can use positional index for both rows and columns (`df.iloc[2,1]`). Otherwise, that is the syntax of pandas.

Comment: btw if you need row no. then don't make 'Timestamp' as index!

Comment: @Anurag, Well that sucks.  If I have a N x M Datetime indexed dataframe (df) where N is the number of rows and M is the number of columns, it is difficult to calculate (df.iloc[N-2,1]/df.iloc[N,M]) - 1.  In other words, is there an easier way to make calculations between different rows AND different columns with a datetime indexed dataframe?  I'm trying to calculate the percent change for 20 time periods over 5,000 rows of data for for 2,000 datasets.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to the **Bonus question**:

```
df.index.get_loc(mytimestampindex) => return the row number in df
```

Answer (score 2):

There is way to do this .
First use `df = df.reset_index()` .
"Timestamp" will be new column added to df , now you get new index as integer.
And you access any row element with `df.loc[]` or `df.iat[]` and you can find any row with specific element .